# Shift loop value to first four bit

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I have a question for a not specific programming language. I can use Shifting and Bitwise Operators

**MyValue** is for example 0xF5 (**1111.0101**). Now I want to count up the first four bits like from 0 up to 15 (each bit combination).

- 0001.0101
- 0010.0101
- 0011.0101
- 0100.0101

Is this correct?

```
for-Loop (counting up to 15, loop variable is LoopVariable)
{
   // Set first four bits to 0 e.g 1111.0101 to 0000.0101
   MyValue = MyValue | (0 << 4)

   // Set first four bits according to current loop e.g. 0000.0101 to 0001.0101
   MyValue = MyValue | (LoopVariable  << 4)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second operation is correct

```
   MyValue = MyValue | (LoopVariable  << 4)
```

it sets high bits to bits of `LoopVariable`.

The first is not:

```
   MyValue = MyValue | (0 << 4)
```

It does not clear any bits, it is no-operation. To clear bits use bit-wise *and* instead of *or*, and apply inverted mask with bit-wise *not*.

Comment: Can you show me an example of the first one please?

Comment: Or do you mean something like this: MyValue &= ~(0xF0 << 4)

Comment: `MyValue = MyValue & ~0xF0`.  Assuming that types would be correct. There's a caveat if `MyValue` is of wider type than `0xF0`, may need to use literal of proper type or cast it. Since your question is language-agnostic, I'm not sure how you do it.

Comment: If you restate the question from "zero four higher bits" to zero everything except lowest four bits, then `MyValue =MyValue & 0xF` is a way to go, no need `~`, and so it is type safe.

Comment: And if you want to obtain 0xF from 4, you can shift and subtract one: `(1 << 4) - 1` - it is 0xF